# Google Maps not showing complete address

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make Google Maps auto complete the address in the format "City - State, Country" however, it is returning this:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

In short: only returns with the city, but i can not know where it is from.

I tested it this way:

```
var input = document.getElementById('address');

$(function () {
    var options = {
       types: ['(cities)']
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
});
```

And JS:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****&libraries=places"></script>
```

If I remove the `types: ['(cities)']` continues without showing the rest of the address.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a working jsbin or jsfiddle for your code to fully investigate the issue?

However, I modified your code and just added an event handler and it works perfectly on my side.

Try this code:

```
function Init () {
var input = document.getElementById('address'); 
var options = { types: ['(cities)']}
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Init);
```

Below is a working code snippet:

```js
function Init() {
  var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var options = {
    types: ['(cities)']
  }
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', Init);
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="address" type="text" size="50" placeholder="City - State, Country" autocomplete="on">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&libraries=places"></script>
```